# Cross domain access permission denied in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, outlook, cross-domain

I am trying to embed OWA (Microsoft Exchange Server 2010) in a web page within an `iframe` but I get a JavaScript error on the OWA page saying Access Denied and then none of the controls within the OWA window work.

I have to use OWA in web page, I read in the form that cross domain does not work properly. Error comes as:

> ### Client Information
>
> **User Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>   **CPU Class:** `undefined`
>   **Platform:** Win32
>   **System Language:** `undefined`
>   **User Language:** `en-US`
>   **CookieEnabled:** true
>
> ### Exception Details
>
> **Date:** Wed Oct 27 2010 10:17:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
>   **Message:** Permission denied for `<http://domain_2>` to get property `HTMLIFrameElement.ownerDocument` from `<domain_1>`.
>   **Url:** `http://domain_2/owa/testuser@exch2k10.com/14.0.639.21/scripts/premium/uglobal.js`
>   **Line:** 1
>
> ### Call Stack
>
> ```
> undefinedError()@:0 window$onerror(&quot;Permission denied for <http://domain_2> to get property HTMLIFrameElement.ownerDocument from <domain_1>.&quot;,&quot;http://domain_2/owa/testuser@exch2k10.com/14.0.639.21/scripts/premium/uglobal.js&quot;,1)@http://domain_2/owa/testuser@exch2k10.com/14.0.639.21/scripts/premium/uglobal.js:1 (domain_1>.&quot;,&quot;http://domain_2/owa/testuser@exch2k10.com/14.0.639.21/scripts/premium/uglobal.js&quot;,1%29@http://domain_2/owa/testuser@exch2k10.com/14.0.639.21/scripts/premium/uglobal.js:1) function Array$get_Length() { return this.length; } function Array$get_Item(index) { return this[index]; } function Array$get_Enumerator() { return new (Owa.Collections.ListEnumerator)(this); } function Array$remove(oItem) { var index = this.indexOf(oItem); if (index > -1) { this.splice(index, 1); } return index > -1; } function Array$removeAt(iIndex) { if (iIndex < this.length) { this.splice(iIndex, 1); return true; } return false; } function Array$add(oItem) { this.push(oItem); } function Array$clone() {
> ```

What I saw is that the error comes when `uglobal.js` which comes with the Exchange in the `iframe` trying to access property of `parent`.

> **Message:** Permission denied for `<http://domain_2>` to get property HTMLIFrameElement.ownerDocument from `<domain_1>`.

Is there any other way by which I can use OWA in my page?

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/7995223/819417

Comment: @Cees: I agree that they both have the same underlying problem, but this question is about how to configure OWA to get around the problem, whereas that question is about how to avoid it in your own code.

Answer (score 3):

That's the cross domain policy restricting you. It's designed to prevent cross site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Basically, only pages from the same domain, protocol and port can alter each other's content.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issues when trying to make cross domain calls. For IE8 you can use the following approach

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", "http://domain2");
xdr.onload = function(){
    //your code
};
xdr.send();
```

Additionally in IE only for testing purposes there is an option to add the specific address (domain1 in your case) to the trusted list `Tools>Security>Trusted Sites>Sites` and allow it to make cross domain requests by going to `custom level` and selecting `Access data sources across domains`. Please ensure the second is used only for testing.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? if not let me know or else kindly close the loop on this. Thanks

Comment: Is there a similar solution like this for other browsers, like Firefox or Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

If no JSONP solution exists, build a server side proxy.

Comment: can u tell me little bit more about server side proxy soln..  thanks for the reply

Comment: @R_Dhorawat Use a server side language to request the file - then you can access it, or if you require client interaction - to serve it to your front end.

Comment: client interaction is there so even if i get the required file once...  problem will be still there. because if we click on some part of that frame there is other request will be there...