# Permission denied to access property 'document'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using following script there, form this script on my page add iframe and I want to get iframe html.

```
<script src="http://ads.sonobi.com/ttj?id=881134" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Problem is in iframe there is inner iframe.

Javascript following function using for get content of ifrmae

```
document.getElementById('f1').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

When I run this will show following error

```
Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

How to solve the problem of permission denied.

Comment: you cannot access the DOM in a iframe that is from a different domain than your executing script. this is called cross site scripting

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7995223/819417

Answer (score 4):

**You can't.**

Why? It's a security feature to stop Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

For example, you have an iframe that loads `www.facebook.com`. If this security feature wasn't implemented, you could easily fetch data from that site. From cookies, to what content is on the page.

There is more helpful information about this here: http://www.veracode.com/security/xss

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the JS, but you can't get HTML from an remote page with javascript. Try PHP's cURL.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var frame = document.getElementById('f1');
var doc = frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument;
var html = doc.document.body.innerHTML
```

Source: [Frame/IFrame contentDocument Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp).

Comment: Actually, there is still problem.