# How to remove social icon bar from wistia videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using wistia iframe video in my webpage,

html:

```
<div id="iframeContainer"><iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/bqur1fvyag?videoFoam%5BmaxWidth%5D=420&videoFoam%5BminHeight%5D=234" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="" height=""></iframe>
```

Jquery:

```
<script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
```

Now i need to hide social icon bar. I searched in google for wistia videos.

Still am struggling , can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to check the wistia documentation. What have you tried to this point? Looks like you have to configure it in your customization settings on their site http://wistia.com/doc/embedding

Comment: in that.. no scripts at all.. it shows like this only http://wistia.com/doc/customizing-your-video#social_bar .. i think, have to edit in this code //fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js

Comment: You cannot. You don't own that code. You need to uncheck all those checkboxes. This is out of the scope of the help this site provides. You should contact wistia support instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsbin for your solution http://jsbin.com/coforebezo/1/edit?html,js,output

You have to use embed script for your video to hide the social icons.

If you want to more customize the video, please refer the documentations 
http://wistia.com/doc/embed-options#socialbar_plugin

Comment: You cannot do through iframe. It will throw permission error. If you really want to customize the videos. its better use embed code recommended by http://wistia.com

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/7ah9hk6d/

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758708/permission-denied-to-access-property-document you cannot get iframe content for crossdomain

Comment: Its working perfectly fine, I just checked in all browser. and If you are trying to change video code. Do change in div as well

Comment: how to remove black bar on left and right side in my video? Thanks

Comment: You have to make the div width and height according to your video size  see this http://jsbin.com/zivorohori/1/edit?html,output