# jQuery doesn't change iframe background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a `select` box in my page and it looks in this way:

```
<select id="bgselector" onchange="bg(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
 <option value="0.png" id="btn1">1. Default skin</option>
 <option value="1.png" id="btn2">2. MK7 Collage</option>
 <option value="3.jpg" id="btn3">3. Full Darkness</option>
</select>
```

When I click an option (thanks to the `bg();` function) the background of the page changes. By the way there is also an iframe inside my body.

When the body background changes, I want that my iframe changes the background too, so I wrote the following code:

```
$(function() {
    var iframe_body = $('iframe').contents().find('body');

    var set_bg = function(url) {
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity', 1.0);
    }
    $('#bgselector').change(function() {
        set_bg($(this).val());
    });
     $('#btn1').click(function(){
        set_bg('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/0.png');
    });
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        set_bg('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/1.png');
        $("body").css('opacity', 1.0);
    });
    $('#btn3').click(function(){
        set_bg('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/backgrounds/3.jpg');
        $("body").css('opacity', 0.9);
    });
});
```

With the jQuery above, when I change the background of my body, the background of the page in my iframe changes.

The problem is that when I change the page in the iframe, the background changes into the original one (instead of the same of the body). How could I fix this?

Comment: is the changed page still under your domain ? Why not set the bg again when changing the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the previous background of the `iframe` as a query parameter when you change the iframe's content.

Assume your iframes are:

- website.com/1
- website.com/2

when you change your iframe's url from `website.com/1` to `website.com/2`, make the url to `website.com/2?bg=xxx.png`, you can then process the background issue use either sever side effort or front-end side effort.

**Update**

When you're changing your iframe's background, first get the current background of your iframe

`var bg = $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-image')`

then you set a new `src` to your `iframe` element

`$('selector_to_your_iframe').attr('src', 'your_new_iframe_src' + '?bg=' + bg)`

then you can set the background image in your script when processing `your_new_iframe_src`

```
//PHP Code
<html>
<head>
</head>
if(isset($_GET['bg'])){
    echo "<body style='background-image:url({$_GET['bg']}) no-repeat center;'>";
}
else{
    echo "<body>"
}
//contiunes to process the rest of webpage
```

In this manner, you can maintain the iframe background image even you change it.

Of course there is some front-end way to do this, like set the previous background image in `cookies` or `local storage`, but I won't dig it too deep.

Comment: Could you make an example with the code? I am new with jQuery. If yes I'll +1 and accept.

Comment: you can only do this if you add code to the external site. if its not your site this will be a problem.

Comment: @Max Please note that _With the jQuery above, when I change the background of my body, the background of the page in my iframe changes._

Comment: @jasonslyvia we still dont know to what page he changes the scr of his iframe.

Comment: I change using urls of mk7vrlist.altervista.org. I'm using webpages inside my website

Answer (score 0):

This will set your background to the selected option in your dropdown everytime you change the contents of the iframe as long as your iframe's scr is under the same domain.

[Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + $("#bgselector").val() + ')');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Already has an accepted answer, then, just as a furder reference...

If you want the same image as a `background` on the main `body` && `iFrame`
Why don't you use a `Transparent Iframe Background`??

In the main page:

```
<iframe ... frameborder=0 ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>
```

In the iframe...

```
<body style="background-color:transparent">
```

no need to worry about `iframe background`any more...