# Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' - while accessing content from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="640px" height="590px" id="pagefrm" src="http://support.domain.com/controller/method"></iframe>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                $("#pagefrm").contents().find("body").append("Hi");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In above code, I am trying to append text or scripts from parent page. But when ever I use .append(), .html(), .prepend() etc. using jquery, its returning error - Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'.

Comment: [**Same-origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document

Comment: You cant do anything if Permission is denied from the Remote Website.

Comment: what about if both parent page and iframe page both are on same domain?