# How to force an iframe's parent page to scroll to top automatically when the user navigates in the iframe?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

*** Please note: cross-domain scenario ***

I have an iframe which has *no* scrollbar, but much more taller than the browser window, so the vertical scrolling is done by the browser's main vertical scrollbar. However there is a disturbing feature of this: When the navigation done in scrolled down state the scroll is not reset to top in the parent.

I would like to reset this scroll to the init top state automatically when page navigation occurs in the iframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your iframe has a cross domain issue (pointing to somewhere other than your website) You can't:
[error : Permission denied to access property 'document'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)

But if not, you can do it using this code. add this to scripts in page:

```
var myframe = window.frames[0].window;
myframe.onscroll = function(){if(myframe.scrollY == myframe.scrollMaxY){window.scrollTo(0,0);}};
//Thanks Diodeus!
```

Or you can select it by `getElementById` or other similars and give the reference to `myframe` variable. This triggers an event when you scroll down in the iframe and then scrolls the whole document up.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook an `onload` event to the iframe. It is one of the few hooks you can get in a cross-domain scenario.

```
document.getElementById("some_iframe").onload = function (){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have no access to the parent page. It is an other providers other application in an other domain

Comment: Ah. I thought you were managing the parent page, not the iframe.