# Button working in chrome, but not firefox or ie?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

Hey everyone so i have a custom login button which calls `Meteor.loginWithTwitter();` like so:

[image: pic]

This works great on Chrome, the twitter popup pops up etc.., but on Firefox and IE It doesnt do anything and spits this out in the console:
`Error: Permission denied to access property "call"`

in

`events.js:423:10`

Any idea as to whats going on here, and why it works in Chrome but not the others? I went and added the deault login buttons `{{> loginButtons}}` just to test and it does work on the other browsers but still outputs the same error.

Comment: Could we have the `loginbutton` template's code please?

Comment: @BraveKenny Yep, heres a pic: http://prntscr.com/70h9q6

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is elsewhere. Are you getting no warnings or errors in chrome console?

Comment: Also, don't inline images. Put actual snippets of code if you want any meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same code in your event helper in IE/Firefox console. This should give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Yes using `Meteor.loginWithTwitter();` directly in the console makes the login and popup work but the error still persists. Weird huh? And no, im not gettings any kind of errors in the Chrome console.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document. Overall it seems that your issue is unrelated to meteor and is something to do with your server configuration/certificate or a mix of two.

Comment: This is being run locally. Same problem persists when its live though as well.

Comment: If you replace loginWithTwitter to Accounts.loginWithPassword, does that work?

Comment: and by work I mean, does that throw the same error? *Meteor.loginWithPassword()

Answer (score 0):

Ok so removing `ecwyne:polymer-elements` package did the trick.