# Permission denied to access property 'document' in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

permission denied to access property document on Firefox but it works on internet explorer. is their any way to remove access restriction

the code is as below
parent.window.frames['rapstatusbar'].document.getElementById("errorDisplayArea").innerHTML = errorToDisplay;

where rapstatusbar isa an iframe. 
errorDisplayArea is an element of another JSP which is linked to current jsp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error : Permission denied to access property 'document'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995223/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)

Comment: when, where, and how are you getting that error? not enough code shown...

Comment: when i want to access element of parent jsp , it shows the error mentioned above.