# Error: Permission denied to access property "document" in same domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to fetch full content from domain 
http://www.domainname.com/dingcovers/ to http://www.domainname.com/eevelle/dingcovers/

Note: This domainname same for both. And I have created a page like "dingcovers" into (domainname.com/eevelle/dingcovers/) and just wato to show data into it from domainname.com/dingcovers/. But I got:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

Comment: I have used iframe like
 <iframe id="ifrm_another_page_content_dingcovers" width="100%" src="http://domainname.com/dingcovers/" type="text/html"></iframe>

Comment: there is a good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22868063/3086860