# jQuery, Shadowbox + Facebook JS SDK: access to property ownerDocument denied

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, shadowbox

In a custom CMS, the website's editors may enable a sidebar-box in order to display one of the latest Facebook-Fanpage-Posts and it's associated comments.

For selecting the appropiate Post, a form is opened via Shadowbox = as iFrame.

Within this iFrame

- FB Javascript SDK is initialized
- Fanpage-Posts are fetched (with Access-Token)
- A Dropdown is being populated with the Posts (first 20 chars of each post)

When an editor selects one of the posts excerpts in the dropdown, two further input fields (disabled for user-input) are populated with the post-id / the full post message.

On hitting a SAVE button, those two values (id + message that have been written into the disabled input fields before) are supposed to be saved, and the shadowbox shall close.

Everything works fine, except the saving part in Firefox:
Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument' in jquery-1.6.4.min.js line 5151.

The code evoking the error (in accordance with the error log):

```
    Sizzle.isXML = function( elem ) {
    // documentElement is verified for cases where it doesn't yet exist
    // (such as loading iframes in IE - #4833) 
    var documentElement = (elem ? elem.ownerDocument || elem : 0).documentElement;

return documentElement ? documentElement.nodeName !== "HTML" : false;
```

};

The main CMS page and the iFrame contents are both served from the same domain, I think I may rule out Cross-Domain-Errors?

Comment: This does look like a cross domain permission error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030220/cross-domain-access-permission-denied-in-iframe for a similar question with several responses.

Comment: how can it be a crossdomain error if both the main and the iframe site are served from the same domain, port and protocol?
might it be caused by the embedded FB JS SDK skript?
If so, any workarounds? THANKS!!

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing all the code, but the error is consistent with a cross-domain permission issue. Do you have an example hosted somewhere public?

Comment: Shadowbox clones per-link elements. If the SAVE button it validating against the original link `id` and not the form in `#sb-player` then maybe that's the issue?